# How can I use Kernel.apply for macro function

Tags: elixir

[Kenel.apply/3 function](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3) of elixir could not call function which is defined by macro.

Example,

```
defmodule Hoge1 do
  for fun_name <- [:foo, :bar] do
    defmacro unquote(fun_name)(arg) do
      apply(Hoge2, unquote(fun_name), [arg])
    end
  end
end

defmodule Hoge2 do
  for fun_name <- [:foo, :bar] do
    defmacro unquote(fun_name)(arg) do
      IO.puts "hoge2"
    end
  end
end
```

above case, if I call as `Hoge1.foo`, error raise.
(`undefined function: Hoge2.foo/1`)

I can call `Hoge2.foo/1` directly.
(It output "hoge2")

Can I call with Kernel.apply/3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` will only work with functions, not with macros. First go ahead and check if you really need macros, because a lot of problems can (and should) be solved just with functions. In this case you can just use `def` in place of `defmacro`:

```
defmodule Hoge1 do
  for fun_name <- [:foo, :bar] do
    def unquote(fun_name)(arg) do
      apply(Hoge2, unquote(fun_name), [arg])
    end
  end
end

defmodule Hoge2 do
  for fun_name <- [:foo, :bar] do
    def unquote(fun_name)(arg) do
      IO.puts "hoge2"
    end
  end
end
```

If your solution strictly requires macros, you can generate a macro call directly instead of using `apply`:

```
Hoge2.unquote(fun_name)(arg)
```

To make the `Hoge2` macros available to `Hoge1`, you also need to require `Hoge2` inside `Hoge1`. The complete solution would look like this

```
defmodule Hoge2 do
  for fun_name <- [:foo, :bar] do
    defmacro unquote(fun_name)(arg) do
      IO.puts "hoge2"
    end
  end
end

defmodule Hoge1 do
  require Hoge2

  for fun_name <- [:foo, :bar] do
    defmacro unquote(fun_name)(arg) do
      Hoge2.unquote(fun_name)(arg)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you!
I used not "defmacro" but "def".
It works well!